# Functions with closed-form expectations under Gaussian PDF

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I need to compute Gaussian integrals of the form:
$$
\mathcal{I}[f] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{N}\left(x\mid\mu,\sigma^2\right) f(x) \, dx,
$$
where $\mathcal{N}\left(x\mid\mu,\sigma^2\right)$ is a [normal PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and variance $\sigma^2 \in \mathbb{R}_+$. (That is, the integral is the expectation of $f$ under a Gaussian PDF.)

I am wondering for which classes of $f$ - for arbitrary $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ - the integral $\mathcal{I}[f]$ has known closed-form solutions.

For example, by looking [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) I could find the following cases:

- $f$ is a polynomial;
- $f$ is an exponential;
- $f$ is a squared exponential (e.g., another Gaussian PDF);
- $f$ is the error function (e.g., as in a Gaussian CDF), or some functions involving erf.

Are there other notable cases?

(Please note that I am not interested in numerical solutions, such as quadrature.)

Comment: What other kinds of f are you interested in?

Comment: Any that have a closed form. But let's say continuous and differentiable.

Comment: I meant, is there a specific function that you are hoping would have a closed form solution? Or are you just interested in a comprehensive list for its own sake?

Comment: The latter. The rationale is that I am choosing an $f$ for a machine learning algorithm I am building (clearly, different $f$'s will bring different properties, but it's up to me to figure out the effect on the algorithm). I am wondering what is the set of $f$'s I can choose from in the first place.

Comment: [Hennequin and Lengyel](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03110) use the closed-form for *rectified* polynomials to obtain some moment-closures for stochastic neural networks. The expectation of the logistic sigmoid is sometimes approximated by approximating it as a re-scaled error function. Expectations of sine/cosine are possible as a special case of the exponential $\exp(i\theta) = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$.